# Is there a way to only have StyleCop documentation requirements SA1600 on public methods/properties?

Tags: c#, resharper, stylecop

I've been using XMLDoc for a few years now, and have definitely grown into the mindset for supplying quality documentation for public methods and properties.

However under StyleCop (and particularly its Resharper highlighting) I've noticed that the documentation requirements apply to identically to public, internal, protected and private methods. This seems a  little counter-intuative to me, so I would ideally like to suppress it down to suggestions at least for private methods.

Unfortunately it does seem as if the suppress setting is only across all public, internal, private, etc. Am I missing something or is this by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on the "Documentation Rules" tab in the StyleCop settings, the Detailed Settings contains "Ignore privates" and "Ignore internals" checkboxes.

Comment: Excellent. Resharper seems to obey the style cop settings too. Just what I was looking for